# "Invalid memory access" when calling Delphi DLL from Java

Tags: java, delphi, dll

We have a DLL, written in Delphi, being called by a Java app. Initially we had issues when using PChar or ShortString but we changed these to PAnsiChar and all our issues seemed to have been solved.

However, when we started deploying the DLL to our clients, about 50% of the installations get the following error: Invalid memory access.

The very first line in the DLL is to write to our log file but that is not happening which indicated there is a problem between the Delphi and Java datatypes. Does anybody have any ideas as to what Delphi and Java data types work well together?

Delphi DLL code:

```
function HasCOMConnection(COMServerName: PAnsiChar): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLog('HasCOMConnection: DLL entered');
  Result := HasConnection(COMServerName);
end;

exports
  HasCOMConnection;
```

Calling from Java:

```
    private interface IPMOProcessLabResult extends com.sun.jna.Library {
        boolean HasCOMConnection(String COMServerName);
    }

    private boolean canConnectToCOMServer() {
        try {
            IPMOProcessLabResult lib = (IPMOProcessLabResult) Native.loadLibrary(config.libraryName, IPMOProcessLabResult.class);
            return lib.HasCOMConnection(config.comServerName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            new AppendLog(new Date(), this.getClass() + "\t" + ex.getClass() + "\t" + "Exception while trying to connect to COMServer: " + ex.getMessage(), "debug");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the comments in your last question and below my answer, too? From them I can tell, that Java string and Delphi PAnsiChar are not compatible! PAnsiChar is a pointer to a C-style one-byte-per-character array/string

Comment: As far as I know, Java strings use 16 bit characters like Delphi Strings. So at first glance use Char and PChar at Delphi side. Only very old Delphi version is using 8 bits chars. Which Delphi version do you use? (Edit you question to add the details).

Comment: @fpiette He uses Delphi 10.4

Comment: Make sure your native code doesn't throw any unhandled exception.

Comment: Isn't this just stdcall vs cdecl? Also, I suspect it should be `LongBool` on the Delphi side.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Java JNA documentation](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/overview-summary.html#strings), a Java `String` is converted to a `const char*` when passed to native code:

> Java `String`s perform the same function as the native types `const char*` and `const wchar_t*` (NUL-terminated arrays). In order to use the proper type when calling a native function, we have to introduce some sort of annotation to identify how the java `String`should be converted. **Java `String`s are normally converted to `char*` since this is the most common usage of strings.** Strings are automatically converted to a NUL-terminated array of `char`across the function call. Returned `char*` values are automatically copied into a `String` if the method signature returns `String` (`strdup`, for example).

So the use of `PAnsiChar` on the Delphi side is correct when passing a `String` as-is.

However, Delphi strings in Delphi 2009+ are natively encoded in UTF-16, same as Java strings.  So, it would be more efficient (or at least, no risk of data loss) to use `WString` on the Java side:

> The `WString` class is used to identify wide character strings. Unicode values are copied directly from the Java char array to a native `wchar_t` array.

And use `PWideChar` on the Delphi side to match, eg:

```pascal
function HasCOMConnection(COMServerName: PWideChar): Boolean; stdcall;
```

```java
private interface IPMOProcessLabResult extends com.sun.jna.Library {
    boolean HasCOMConnection(WString COMServerName);
}
```

---

That being said, there are 2 other problems with your code.

Per the same JNA documentation, a Java `boolean` maps to a native `int`, not a `bool`, so your Delphi code needs to use `Integer` (or `Int32`) or better `LongBool`, eg:

```pascal
function HasCOMConnection(COMServerName: PAnsiChar{or PWideChar}): LongBool; stdcall;
```

More importantly, if a native library uses the `stdcall` calling convention, you have to extend `IPMOProcessLabResult` from [`com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary.html), eg:

```java
private interface IPMOProcessLabResult extends com.sun.jna.StdCallLibrary
```

Otherwise, if you extend from `com.sun.jna.Library` then you need to use `cdecl` on the native side:

```pascal
function HasCOMConnection(COMServerName: PAnsiChar{or PWideChar}): LongBool; cdecl;
```

Comment: I'd question the `boolean` mapping. I'd expect that to map to a 4 byte Windows boolean, `LongBool` in Delphi.